# How to make a image transparent out of defined area?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, surfaceview

I m trying to create a effect where the image is not visible after a specified area..
Example: Like a rabbit in a hole..when it goes under a hole,its body should not be visible slowly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways to composite images with selective transparency: you can use the alpha channel as described in zapl’s answer, or you can clip your drawing of each layer with a [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) or a [Region](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html)—see the `clipxxx` calls you can use when drawing into a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can hide regions of images if you layer multiple images with transparent regions

[image: Uberbunnydrawing]

Image shows bunny on the left, the right side is the view from the side. You need three images (the brown, red and grey one), the part that is not brown/red/grey would be transpararent.

Answer (score 1):

anyway thanks for the tip to @zapl and lawrence .. i used the clip rectangle for the canvas and it worked perfectly..sample code is below..

```
     c.clipRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
      c.clipRect(0, 70, 100, 150, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
      c.drawBitmap(bm, 20, y, null);
```